ChromaDB: Getting 1 ID per PDF
When looking at the amount of ID's in my ChromaDB I see that it is a very high number. In only inserted 5 pdf's in my model, this number corresponds to the number of chunks that are created. How can I set only 1 id per page because I would want to delete certain files from my database using the filename.
def load_documents():
    docs = []
    for file in os.listdir(FOLDER_PATH):
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdf_path = FOLDER_PATH + "/" + file
            loader = UnstructuredLoader(pdf_path)
            docs.extend(loader.load())
    docs = filter_complex_metadata(docs)
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=800, chunk_overlap=200)
    chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)
    return chunks



def populate_database(docs):
    db = Chroma(persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH,        embedding_function=OllamaEmbeddings(model=embed_model))
    db.add_documents(docs)
    return db


from chromadb.client import ChromaClient

def insert_pdf_into_chromadb(chromadb, pdf_filename, chunks):
    file_id = hash(pdf_filename)  
    for page_number, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        chromadb.insert(
            ids=[f"{file_id}_page_{page_number}"],  # Unique ID per page
            documents=[chunk],
            metadatas=[{"file_id": file_id, "page": page_number, "filename": pdf_filename}],
        )

def delete_pdf_from_chromadb(chromadb, pdf_filename):
    file_id = hash(pdf_filename)
    results = chromadb.query(
        query={"metadata": {"file_id": file_id}}
    )
    chunk_ids = [result["id"] for result in results]
    chromadb.delete(ids=chunk_ids)

